# XPath code to get value in a list

Tags: xslt, xpath

lets say I have this XML :

```
<myxml>
    <Labels>
        <Label>
            <id>id1</id>
            <value>abc</value>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <id>id2</id>
            <value>def</value>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <id>id3</id>
            <value>ghi</value>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <id>id4</id>
            <value>jkl</value>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <id>id5</id>
            <value>mno</value>
        </Label>
    </Labels>
</myxml>
```

And I would like to display the value "def" and "jkl".

I'm looking for the XPath expression that allow me to take the value of a label where the id is "id2".

I've tried with this :

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="Labels/Label[id = 'id2']/value"/>
```

but it's not working ...
Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance for your answer,
Best regards

Comment: If you post a full XSLT example, it will be easier to diagnose the problem. I'm just guessing based on the snippet your provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the root to your xpath?

```
<xsl:value-of select="myxml/Labels/Label[id = 'id2']/value" />
```

Also, `disable-output-escaping` is typically unnecessary.

Comment: But id is tag and not attribute

Comment: In fact, I have a <xsl:template match="myxml">

Comment: @Tim is this `xxl:value-of` the only thing in that template?

Comment: XSLT is overkill if you just need to get an XPath. Don't forget that in most languages (and even with shell commands), you can look for an XPath in an XML file...

Comment: @Aurélien XSLT may be the only language he's using; we don't know, but this is the solution he asked for. If you want to make suggestions, post them under his question, since he won't get notified about comments you make here, unless you specify his @(username) .